Flink SQL Timestamp to time with miliseconds hh:mm:sss
How can i convert timestamp to hh:mm:sss format in flink sql?

Does this not work?
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(timestamp_column, 'HH:mm:ss.SSS')
Or could show us the sample input and the code that you tried

There is Built In Functions documentation page
DATE_FORMAT(eventTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd')


You need to use the Time string Function to return the 'hh:mm:ss' format
found here
flink Documentation of Datetime
